# Email is not getting generated through Airflow after using EmailOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

In Airflow,email is not getting generated using EmailOperator. Although the task is showing that email is directed to the mentioned email address but I can see no emails getting generated.

Expected:
Email needs to get generated on EMAILID

CODE SNIPPET:

```
 email_alert = EmailOperator(
            task_id='email_alert',
            to=email,
            subject=f'Alert: No files received for project {dag_id.upper()} for {{{{ds}}}}',
            html_content=f'<p>The Data files for project {dag_id.upper()} are not present. <br>Impact: The ingestion will not be done for today </p>',
            dag=dag
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your message is missing code to simulate the issue locally.

Here are a few thoughts:

1. Can you confirm the SMTP server settings are configured correctly in airflow.cfg? [Official Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html)
2. Are you sure the email address is correct or not arrived in your Junk folder?
3. Can you confirm email_alert task is included in your upstream or downstream tasks, and its successfully running?

Comment: email_alert task is running successfully and checked whether emails are landing in junk folder or not.They are not landing anywhere in spam or even trash.Could you please specify what values and fields are mandatory in smtp part of airflow.cfg file ?

Comment: Below parameters are present:
smtp_host = 
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = 
smtp_port = 
smtp_password = 
smtp_mail_from =

Comment: @DhanashreeShekatkar Which service are you using? SendGrid, gmail or another service? Can you confirm this is working? [Checkout this guide if you have not set this up](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/use-emailoperator-airflow-dag)

Comment: I am using this :
email_backend = airflow.contrib.utils.sendgrid.send_email

Comment: I am facing same issue since November 2023. Earlier it was working. However, using python SMTP it is working fine.